# Summing up the elements in a std::integer_sequence

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

For educational purposes I try to create a `std::integer_sequence` and sum up its elements as a parameter pack. I expected this to be straightforward and wrote the code below.

Step 1: Created the set of add()-operations to properly process homogeneous , integer-based, parameter packs.  Tested with the `add<0,1,2,3>()`-call and worked.

Step 2: In this step i wanted to pass a `std::integer_sequence` as a template-parameter, to sum up the integers in the sequence. I failed, see the commented out code.

How can I pass a `std::integer_sequence` as a template parameter?

One error message is that no instance of the function template total matches the call.  Why? I expected an integer sequence to be equivalent to an `int` parameter pack.

The other error message says that the `Args` template parameter is non-constant.  How could that be? I expect that to be a follow up error, but I saw this error combination a lot in my experiments.

I'm using the Microsoft VC++ 2017 compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
T add(T first) {
    return first;
}

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
T add(T car, Args... cdr) {
    return car + add(cdr...);
}

template <int ... Args>
int total() {
    return add(Args...);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    int s1 = 
        total<0, 1, 2, 3>();
    std::cout << "s1 = " << s1 << std::endl;

    // The following does not compile:
#if 0
    int s2 = 
        total<std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>>();
    std::cout << "s2 = " << s2 << std::endl;

    static_assert(s1 == s2, "no match");
#endif

    // This should work:
    //
    {
        cout << typeid(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>()).name() << endl;;
        cout << std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>().size << endl;;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

... Later, after a lot of helpful comments. I learnt a lot and have now the following working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
constexpr T add(T first) {
    return first;
}

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr T add(T car, Args... cdr) {
    return car + add(cdr...);
}

template <int ... Args>
constexpr int total() {
    return add(Args...);
}

template<int... Args>
constexpr int total(std::integer_sequence<int, Args...>) {
    return total<Args...>();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    constexpr int s1 =
        total<0, 1, 2, 3>();
    std::cout << "s1 = " << s1 << std::endl;

    // The following now compiles. Oh, happy day!
#if 1
    constexpr int s2 =
        total(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4> {});

    std::cout << "s2 = " << s2 << std::endl;

    static_assert(s1 == s2, "no match");
#endif

    // This should work:
    //
    {
        cout << typeid(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>()).name() << endl;;
        cout << std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>().size << endl;;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Copy and paste error messages. Please, just paste the text. Writing a sentence describing the error is more work for you and less help to us than just pasting it verbatim.

Comment: The error messages are localized, so I added a translation that most of the readers can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to add an overload for `total` and call it differently:

```
template<int... Args>
int total(std::integer_sequence<int, Args...> ) {
    return add(Args...);
}
```

and than calling

```
nt s2 = 
    total(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>>{});
```

This would fix calling issue. In order to use the result of the function in `static_assert` , you'd also need to make sure it (and the variable storing it's result) are marked as `constexpr`.

Answer (score 7):

This would be much easier to do with [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template<class T, T... Args>
constexpr T total(std::integer_sequence<T, Args...> = {}) {
    return (Args + ...);
}

int main() {
    int s2 = 
        total(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>{});
    // Or calling directly
    int s1 = total<int, 0, 1, 2, 3>();
}
```

Notice the defaulted `std::integer_sequence` argument, so if you pass an integer sequence it will deduce the `Args` parameter.

If you want to be able to call it with a `std::integer_sequence` type in the template, just make a helper function:

```
template<class IntegerSequence>
constexpr auto total_of(IntegerSequence argument = {}) {
    return total(argument);  // Will deduce `T` and `Args`
}

total_of<std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I expected an integer sequence to be equivalent to an int parameter pack.

It isn't: a `std::integer_sequence` is a type; so

```
total<std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>>();
```

can match to a template `total()` function that receive a type

```
template <typename T>
int total ()
 { return ???; }
```

the problem is that from the type `T` you can't easily extract the integer sequence.

> How can I pass a std::integer_sequence as a template parameter?

The solution (well... a possible solution) is the partial specialization.

Unfortunately, a function can't be partial specialized.

But if `total` is a `struct` (or a `class`) all is different.

You can write `total` as follows

```
template <typename>
struct total;

template <typename T, T ... Is>
struct total<std::integer_sequence<T, Is...>>
   : public std::integral_constant<T, (Is + ...)>
 { };
```

so you can use it in the following way

```
constexpr auto s2 { total<std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>>::value };
```

Off Topic: declare `constexpr` the variables you want to use in a `static_assert()` test.

The following is a full compiling C++17 example (`total` struct renamed `total2` to avoid collision with `total()` function)

```
#include <utility>

template <typename>
struct total2;

template <typename T, T ... Is>
struct total2<std::integer_sequence<T, Is...>>
   : public std::integral_constant<T, (Is + ...)>
 { };

template <typename T>
constexpr T add (T first)
 { return first;}

template <typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr T add (T car, Args ... cdr)
 { return car + add(cdr...); }

template <int ... Args>
constexpr int total ()
 { return add(Args...); }

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto s1 { total<0, 1, 2, 3>() };
   constexpr auto s2 { total2<std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>>::value };

   static_assert(s1 == s2);
 }
```

Comment: I did not get this thru the Microsoft compiler, though I switched it to C++17.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected an integer sequence to be equivalent to an int parameter pack.

But you can see it isn't by writing out the two expansions of:

```
template <int ... Args> int total();
```

the first case is

```
total<0, 1, 2, 3>();
// => Args... is (0, 1, 2, 3)
```

which is a valid integer pack, and the second is

```
total<std::make_integer_sequence<int, 4>>();
// => Args... must be std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 1, 2, 3>
```

which is clearly nothing like an integer pack. Link to the documentation for [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) for reference.

If you want to turn that integer sequence back into the original parameter pack passed to `make_integer_sequence`, you need to use the template argument deduction overload SergeyA's answer shows:

```
template<int... Args>
int total(std::integer_sequence<int, Args...> ) {
    return add(Args...);
}
```

(the function parameter is a dummy just to allow `Args...` to be deduced).

The fold expression is anyway much nicer than the old-style recursion if you can use it, though.